# Cakephp Pagination without number

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I'm trying to find out how to display pagination buttons withou displaying numbers over the buttons. In documentation there is no word about this, but i assume that it's possible to manage this thing.
[image]

Comment: You can do anything you want - it's PHP afterall.  But if you're asking "Can I use $this->Paginator->numbers(); to display something other than numbers?"... I'm guessing probably not.  For your sake, I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: and what do you want to show instead of numbers?

Comment: just button, problem solved using jquery and input into this button html('')

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with Javascript or simply CSS by hide the text content.

For example if you paginated your results in like this means

```
<div id="paginator">
<?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('Previous'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Paginator->first('First'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('class' => 'number', 'first' => false, 'last' => false, 'separator' => '-')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Paginator->last('Last'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Paginator->next('Next'); ?> 
</div>
```

Using CSS you can hide as follow

```
<style>
#paginator span
{
 border:1px saddlebrown solid;
 padding:3px;
 margin: 2px;
 background: #1e7ec8;
 color: brown;
}
#paginator span a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
#paginator .number a
{
 color:transparent;
}
</style>
```

Also using Javascript or Jquery you can set text of numbers class empty by following

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.number').text('');
    });
```